# TensorFlow dataset causes kernel to kill the process during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset, generator

I want to create a data pipeline for training TensorFlow models. The data is stored in very large HDF5 files (250+ GB).

I have written a pipeline that works for smaller input files, but ultimately gets killed by the kernel after consuming too much RAM+swap (verified this through monitoring).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py

class TestGenerator:
    """
    Implements a generator that can be used by tf.data.Dataset.from_generator 
    to produce a dataset for any test data.
    """
    def __init__(self, src, dset):
        self.src = src
        self.dset = dset
        self.output_signature = (
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.uint64)
        )

    def __call__(self):
        """This is needed for tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to work."""
        with h5py.File(self.src, 'r', swmr=True) as f:
            for sample in f[self.dset]:
                yield sample[0], sample[1]

gen = TestGenerator('h5file.h5', 'dset_path')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen, 
    output_signature=gen.output_signature
)

for sample in dataset:
    pass
```

At first, I thought this might be a problem of the h5py module, so I tested it separately:

```
with h5py.File('h5file.h5', 'r', swmr=True) as f:
    for sample in f['dset_path']:
        pass
```

This works without problems. This leads to the conclusion that TensorFlow is responsible for the memory problem. What irritates me is that I assumed that TensorFlow fetches the needed data on-the-fly and therefore avoids memory problems.

The code is tested and works fine for smaller files. I also tested versions where I used `dataset.prefetch` before iterating, but with the same result.

Does TensorFlow load the whole dataset under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

If you open task manager, at time of importing tensorflow and creating your model, will it show extremely high values of GPU memory reserved?

If so, it may not be the size of either the model or the data, but the fact that tensorflow reserves as much memory as possible for all model training.

For my personal example, my 3080 has 10 GB of Dedicated GPU Memory and tensorflow took 9.7GB of it.

If this is the case, have a look at the set_memory_growth method on https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth.

Using this reduced my Dedicated GPU Memory usage from 9.7GB to in between 3.2GB and 4 GB.

EDIT: I'm not sure at which point it will aim to allocate that Memory, but if you attempt to train the model and keep an eye on Task Manager Performance for the GPU you should find if it is behaving this way!

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions, but unfortunately, it did not work out. I think this is due to the fact that TF data does not use the GPU and its memory. I monitor the RAM memory allocation on the system with ``watch -n 1 free -m`` and it is easy to see the gradual loss of available space, until it almost hits zero. When that happens, the process is killed by the kernel and the memory is freed.

Comment: Ah that sounds more like you're trying to load in way too much information then? I'm not sure exactly, but can you further define the "RAM+swap" you mention? Because your GPU memory will need 1) enough memory to run the model and 2) enough memory to take the data, that is to say, a copy from RAM into GPU memory?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems I have encountered a bug in the underlying h5py library. What I omitted from my test code above was that I use a slice operator on the dataset, e.g. ``f['dataset'][start:stop]`` to select a subset of the data. The slicing seems to cause the copying of all selected data into RAM. I have found a workaround by using ``itertools.islice`` on the iterable, though. I will leave this topic open as it might help other people.